# Problem finding the string length in C

Tags: c, string

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
  clrscr();
  char a[20],rev[20];
  printf("enter the string");
  scanf("%s",a);
  int len=strlen(a);
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
    rev[i]+=a[len-i-1];
  }
  printf("%d \t  \n string is \t %s",len,rev);
  getch();
}
```

It was correctly working when we gave it a string without spaces:

> input: welcome
>   len:7
>   output: emoclew

When we give it a string with a space:

> input : welcome to this world
>   len:7
>   output:some other ascii chars that I
>   have not seen so far.   and the
>   "len" is again 7 only

When I change the following statement:

> scanf("%s",a) to gets(a);

I get:

> input :welcome to this world
>   len:21
>   output : something different. not the
>   reverse of string...

In this case "len" is correct but the output is wrong.

What is really happening? What is the problem with the above code?

Comment: either don't input a string longer than 20 chars or increase your buffer size (char a[20],rev[20];).

Comment: don't use `scanf("%s",a)`. You cannot know how long the input is, so you must use a function that takes the buffer size as argument.

Comment: Do not use `gets`, it will let you input as many characters as you want, over-run your buffer, and potentially crash your program

Comment: scanf and gets are considered unsafe functions. You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977553/if-one-complains-about-gets-why-not-do-the-same-with-scanfs)

Comment: We have a whole choir going here :)

Comment: @jonsca, yeh, that was a crazy poor formatted post.  I'm done with it, go wild.

Comment: i have used string length below 20.. but the output is same..

Comment: @Lance yes, that was fun.  Why would you use more than one question mark???? Why??? I don't understand.......

Comment: @jonsca, yeh, I missed those, took them out of the title, but forgot them in the text.  I spent most of my time with the quoted result stuff, the quote button has real limits in the editor.  I'll jump back in and take care of it.

Comment: @Lance style....................k what can i do to solve this pbm??

Comment: @thilak, indent your code where appropriate, you can use the quote button for those output excerpts like I did, though they sometimes take a little work.

Comment: @black: `scanf` is not insecure, you can pass it a maximum width specifier.

Comment: @jonsca, thanks for the question mark fixed, I found some other grammar things and patched it up.

Comment: @Lance Roberts oh fine lance. can u provide me a solution to get out this pbm?...

Comment: If you want decent user input, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921 : `scanf("%s")` and `gets()` are just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5):

scanf will not read the entire line. Instead it'll read up to the first space... You need [getline](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html)

Also, I notice you have things with length more than 19 but you allocated space with for 20 chars. Increase that or you get [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan when i use getline method it issues me an linked error. i also gave the input string less than 20 but the output is still not correct...(that is the string is not correctly reversed")

Comment: `scanf` can read an entire line if you use a scanset conversion (`%19[^\n]`) instead of `%s`. `getline` is not part of the standard C library. For portable code, either the scanset conversion or `fgets` is reasonable.

Comment: `getline` is not standard C - you can find a solution similar to that (without the powerful line editing) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921

Comment: the %[ stuff is a nice thing I often tend to forget... about getline, it is in POSIX.1-2008, but I guess the use of conio means the user likely is not on a posix system...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others have said, `rev` is not guaranteed to be initialized to NUL characters, so your `rev[i]+=a[len-i-1];` line can end up with garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

scanf("%[^\t\n]",string);

Comment: And that _still_ has the buffer overflow issue :-)

Comment: @pax: I think the OP is a noob to C. So IMAO we shouldnt petrify him with ugly-looking words like buffer overflow and stuff... ;)

Answer (score 1):

To comments on it:

1. As Armen Tsirunyan wrote, you probably want getline
2. You only have a character array of size 20 - so passing a bigger string will occur in a buffer overflow (which makes your program very insecure - google for buffer overflow attack if you want to know more about it) - this is why you should make sure that you never read more than the size of your character array...